# Updating bound WPF property instantly

Tags: wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I have a textbox on a window that reports the status and or success of a action. It's bound to a property on the ViewModel.

So when a user activates the action that could take some time I wan't to let him know that the action has started in the textBox. Problem is that he doesn't write into the textbox until after the action has finished.

I guess it's because the thread doesn't give the UI the chance to do it's work but not sure.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private string _report;
        public string Report
        {
            get { return _report; }
            set
            {
                _report = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Report");
            }
        }

        public void DoHeavyAction()
        {
            Report += "Heavy action readying";

            ReadyHeavyAction();

            Report += "Heavy action starting";

            var result = DoTheHeavyAction();

            if(!result.success)
            {
                report += "Heavy action failed";
                return;
            }

            Report += result.value;
        }
}
```

In this case the program lags for 2 seconds and then the whole thing appears:

```
Heavy action readying
Heavy action starting
Heavy action failed
```

Instead of appearing one by one.

Can I somehow use the dispatcher to update the View (note I'm using MVVM).

Comment: This can't be right. What is report vs _report vs Report?

Comment: @RitchMelton Just a typo, underscore-report is the private field accessed through the Report property. report += should be Report +=

Comment: Is the recursive call of DoHeavyAction() intended also?

Comment: @RitchMelton Nope sorry about that. It was all supposed to be irrelevant what the heavy action is. It's just to show that something taxing is happening there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's easy. Your heavy operation runs in a separate thread, and you report the progress as

```
Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => {
    Report.value = "Started";
}));
```

---

Edit:
In the actual case the operation is activated by an `ICommand`. The said `ICommand` is dispatched from the UI, therefore it comes in the UI thread. So the problem is that the UI (and its update) is blocked by the heavy operation.

The solution would be to start a new thread on the command arrival, and do the work there. The UI can be updated using the code like the example above.

There are some alternative approaches to this solution, but all of them are anyway starting the task in the background thread, although implicitly. A popular and good one is using a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and updating the state in its [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event (note that this event comes in the UI thread, so you don't need to use the Dispatcher in this case).

Comment: Where do I get the Dispatcher?

Comment: @MetalMikester I think the Dispatcher isn't Static so I should be using the one that comes with the App.Xaml (not sure here). As I'm using MVVM and this is all happening in the ViewModel I have no access to the view. Am I assuming incorrectly?

Comment: You can use this.Dispatcher or the "controlsname".Dispatcher

Comment: Basically, there are several ways. (1) in the UI thread, you get `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`, and save it into a global variable. (2) you ask for a dispatcher at any of your UI controls: `button.Dispatcher`.

Comment: @Tan Using MVVM I have no access to the Control
But I was able to do App.Current.Dispatcher but it didn't work as I hoped. It seems that updating the field isn't the problem. It's probably more to do with the INotifyPropertyChanged waiting until notification or something.

Comment: @Ingó Vals: Oh, that's different then. I use the Cinch v2 MVVM framework, which has a dispatcher helper.

Comment: @Ingó Vals: what does exactly go wrong? Is your view model updated at the correct moment? Or does the view not reflect the changes in the VM?

Comment: @Vlad Yes the view does reflect the changes, just not in the way I hoped. I wanted the info to tick in. So before the heavy work started I wanted "Heavy action readying" to appear, then 2-3 seconds pass while the heavy work is readied then I wanted "Heavy action starting" to appear  etc. Instead a few seconds pass and then the whole report (all things I added to string) appear all at once. It seems that even if I add to the Report property before heavy work is done and propertyChanged event is called it waits to update the UI.

Comment: @MetalMikester I'll check out Cinch, at least for future projects. Thank you.

Comment: @Ingó Vals: well, something is going wrong. Are you sure you are not doing your heavy work in the UI thread?

Comment: @Vlad Not sure, I'm doing this all in a ViewModel class that is coupled from the view itself but set as it's DataContext property. It is however activated by a ICommand from the view so it might be.

Comment: @Ingó Vals: okay, than this is your actual problem :-) The command arrives definitely in the UI thread, so you have to start executing the heavy job in a separate thread.

Comment: Thank, I used just the normal Thread class from .net and it works fine. Not sure how I should award correct answer so it's plain for others who might end up here. Could you add a clause to you answer where you mention that threads started from UI ICommand run on the same thread (probably general knowledge to many but not all).

Answer (score 2):

You can move the 'heavy work' to a background task to get it off the UI thread.

```cs
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoHeavyAction());
Report += "Heavy Action Starting";
task.Wait();
```

Comment: No that's a typo, the text is updated. Just not when I wan't it too.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I just didn't see it as I assumed that the ViewModel would somehow run on a seperate thread because it was coupled from the view (silly me). I used Thread instead of Task but I guess the result is the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and set up ProgressChanged event?

Example:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.ProgressChanged += WorkerReportProgress;
...

private static void WorkerReportProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    report += e.UserState.ToString();
}
```

and in the DoWork do something like

```
private static void DoHeavyAction(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    worker.ReportProgress(0, "Heavy action readying");
    ReadyHeavyAction();
    ...
```